# How many threads in the application? How to set the count of semaphore?

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

The semaphore means to specify the count how many threads can enter into critical region at a time.

The following code set the count is 5.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(5, 5);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 15; ++i)
                {
                    PrintSomething(i);
                    if (i % 5 == 0)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    }
               }
            });
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void PrintSomething(int number)
        {
            semaphore.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine(number);
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Which means each time we can have 5 threads running at any time. The printing result verifies the point.

My question is that I don't see so many threads running. Say 15 threads running, each time only can let 5 threads to be coexisting. There are only two threads.
[image: thread]

Am I misunderstood something?

Comment: Please [edit] your title to something that has meaning. *Semaphore* and *multithreading* are both in the tags, so they're useless redundantly included in the title, and removing them leaves no meaningful content. Your title should explain the problem you're having or the question you're asking in a way that is useful to future readers seeing it in a list of search results.

Comment: You're likely scheduling the work on the thread pool, not a dedicated thread.

Comment: The system gives you an initial thread. You created a worker thread to run the task. That makes two.

Comment: The screen prints 5 numbers each time. Seems 5 threads running at the same time, so I am confused. I get the question from http://dotnetpattern.com/multi-threading-interview-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start one additional thread using `Task.Factory.StartNew()` and that's it. In that thread you are calling the `PrintSomething()` method sequentially, so your thread output screenshot is correct.

Change your code as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SempahoreTest1
{
  class Program
  {
    static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(5, 5);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      for (int i = 1; i <= 15; ++i)
      {
        Task.Factory.StartNew((state) =>
        {
          int number = (int)state;

          PrintSomething(number);
          if (i % 5 == 0)
          {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
          }
        }, i);
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void PrintSomething(int number)
    {
      semaphore.WaitOne();
      try
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread: {0}, Number: {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, number);
      }
      finally
      {
        semaphore.Release();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update:**

A better explanation, how a semaphore works, would be:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SempahoreTest1
{
  class Program
  {
    static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(5, 5);
    static Random    random    = new Random();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Parallel.For(1, 16, PrintSomething);

      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void PrintSomething(int number)
    {
      semaphore.WaitOne();
      try
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread: {0}, Number: {1}, Access granted", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, number);
        // sleep to simulate long running method
        Thread.Sleep(random.Next(1000, 5000));
      }
      finally
      {
        semaphore.Release();
        Console.WriteLine("Thread: {0}, Number: {1}, Semaphore released", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, number);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The parallel loop calls `PrintSomething()` from different threads. On every call the semaphore counter is decreased, until it reaches 0. The next call of `PrintSomething()` blocks on `semaphore.WaitOne()`, until the first calls `semaphore.Release()`, that increments the semaphore counter again. And so on...
The first 5 calls are very fast, because the maximum semaphore count (5) is available. Then, due to the different sleep times, the method call outputs show you, how the semaphore works.

Comment: Yes. Does the [link](http://dotnetpattern.com/multi-threading-interview-questions) using the example to explain the concept wrongly? And in the link, the print result does output 5 each time. It is confusing because I thought there were more than 5 threads.

Comment: @Bigeyes: The example is completely wrong. You can comment out semaphore.WaitOne() and semaphore.Release(), same output. This is because of the sequential calls in the loop from the same thread. It increments 5 times, then waits 2s etc.